# How to write a Python Pandas DataFrame to an .XLS file with specific column type formatting?

Tags: python, dataframe, formatting, xls

I want to first start off by showing an example that works with XLSX (but unfortunately I need XLS and this method does not work for that). Just to re-clarify, **my main issue is the column-type formatting** for a resulting XLS file.

```
# Method that works for XLSX
import pandas as pd

# Example Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
                   'Names': ['Adam','Blake','Chad','Drake','Erak'],
                   'Weights': [1.05, 2.10, 3.15, 4.20, 5.25],
})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'c:\users\3619678\desktop\example_file.xlsx')

# Convert the dataframe to an Excel object
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Get the xlsxwriter workbook and worksheet objects
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Define cell formats
number_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00'})

# Set a certain column's width and apply certain format
worksheet.set_column('A:A', 20, number_format)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Now here is the closest attempt I have so far for the XLS version:

```
import pandas as pd

# Example Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
                   'Names': ['Adam','Blake','Chad','Drake','Erak'],
                   'Weights': [1.05, 2.10, 3.15, 4.20, 5.25],
})

import xlwt

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet
workbook = xlwt.Workbook(r'c:\users\3619678\desktop\example_file.xls')
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)

# Create formats
number_format = xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='0.00')

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row
for x, y in df.iterrows():
    for z, value in enumerate(y):
        worksheet.write(x, z, value, number_format)

# Save/output the workbook
workbook.save(r'c:\users\3619678\desktop\example_file.xls')
```

However the problem with this version is that not only does it not show the headers, it applies the format to all cells. Would really appreciate if someone could help me out, I've spent forever on this!

Comment: Can you specify what kind of formatting you need? If it's just basic number formatting, have you seen https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_column_formats.html ?

Comment: @AMC, yes I have seen that page but the problem is when you change the output URL to XLS instead of XLSX, you can no longer use the add_format or set_column arguments, you get an error similar to "XLWT Writer doesn't have". Either way thank you for looking out, it seems Quinn's solution with the column format dictionary and proper for loop syntax gets the job done!

Comment: _you can no longer use the add_format or set_column arguments, you get an error similar to "XLWT Writer doesn't have"._ What's the exact error message?

Comment: @AMC, sorry I was slightly wrong, the exact error message is: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_format'. This happens when you change the xlsx part of the url to xls, otherwise the formatting piece works. (Also ExcelWriter is indeed able to export XLS files, the problem arises when combining formatting+XLS)

Comment: I only just thought of this, how often will you need to create the XLS file? Is converting it from an XLSX file manually a viable option?

Comment: I need to create 6 different XLS workbooks about once a week, and upload each file into its respective upload slot on a web page. I already have the selenium/chromedriver code that does that nice and quick immediately after file creation as well. It would be best to keep as many steps as automated as possible I think, but yes manual conversion is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using df.to_excel should be much easier

```
df.to_excel('c:\users\3619678\desktop\example_file.xls', sheet_name='sheet1', float_format = "%.2f")
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

[Edit] It looks like this may not be good enough. based on the xlwt documentation, there may not be a tool out there that you want to use. As such, I've added headers and an easy way for you to format by column

```py
import pandas as pd

# Example Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers': [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000],
                   'Names': ['Adam','Blake','Chad','Drake','Erak'],
                   'Weights': [1.05, 2.10, 3.15, 4.20, 5.25],
})

import xlwt

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet
workbook = xlwt.Workbook('example_file.xls')
worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('sheet1',cell_overwrite_ok=True)

# Create dictionary of formats for each column
number_format = xlwt.easyxf(num_format_str='0.00')
cols_to_format = {0:number_format}

for z, value in enumerate(df.columns):
    worksheet.write(0, z, value)

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row
for x, y in df.iterrows():
    for z, value in enumerate(y):
        if z in cols_to_format.keys():
            worksheet.write(x + 1, z, value, cols_to_format[z])
        else: ## Save with no format
             worksheet.write(x + 1, z, value)

# Save/output the workbook
workbook.save('example_file.xls')
```

Comment: Doesn’t this only write XLSX files, though?

Comment: According to the ExcelWriter page, you can write xls files https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

Comment: I guess my answer is just do the same thing but that seems like the easiest solution.

Comment: Hey Quinn, ExcelWriter can indeed write XLS files however the problem is that you lose the capability to format the columns, it shows an error similar to "xlwtwriter doesn't have add_format/set_column". If you keep the first code I shared the same except change the file destination to XLS instead of XLSX, it will work as long as I don't specify column format, but that's what I need.

Comment: @Quinn _According to the ExcelWriter page, you can write xls files_ That doesn't necessarily prove anything about `to_excel()`, although I found another answer which states that you can indeed output XLS files with `to_excel()`.

Comment: _Hey Quinn, ExcelWriter can indeed write XLS files however the problem is that you lose the capability to format the columns, it shows an error similar to "xlwtwriter doesn't have add_format/set_column"._ That's clearly a restriction/limitation of xlwt, right? You're going to need to use another library, I think.

Comment: I think AMC is right. pandas doesn't have a ton of documentation on what engines exist but the main one is openpyxl which doesn't support regular xls files. it doesn't look like what you want is part of pandas, This link is on the xlwt home page and basically says don't use this for new projects, xls files are obsolete. https://groups.google.com/d/msg/python-excel/P6TjJgFVjMI/g8d0eWxTBQAJ

Comment: look at the dictionary col_to_format, and then any column number you want to format can be formatted by adding to that

Comment: @Quinn, thank you very much! That did the trick. I was definitely struggling to get the proper for-loop syntax/logic.

Comment: @sky you should accept an answer once you have found your answer

Comment: _This link is on the xlwt home page and basically says don't use this for new projects, xls files are obsolete._ I had forgotten to ask about that, @SkyLimitTheory is the choice of format out of your control/based on some other requirement?

Comment: By the way, `.iterrows()` tends to be sluggish, it's probably worth using something else, like `.itertuples()`. I think `.to_dict()` could also make for a solid alternative.

Comment: @AMC, Oh yeah in terms of the xls format, unfortunately that requirement is out of my control based on systems at work, but yes if I could choose it would NOT be xls! And thanks for the advice about iterrows, I will try your other alternatives and try to get those to work.

Comment: per @AMC 's comment above, it may be better to convert your xlsx file to an xls file using a converter libreoffice which is opensource has this "libreoffice --convert-to xls myfile.xlsx" https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354043/convert-xlsx-to-xls-in-linux-shell-script

Comment: That's a good suggestion @Quinn, what I had in mind was converting each file manually through Excel lol